# Telegram bot с регистрацией

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота, и не знаю как реализовать регистрацию не при помощи пошагового бота, пользователь вводит Имя, Фамилию, Должность, которые сохраняются в БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите Имя, Фамилию, Должность', parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    first = message.text.split()[0]
    last = message.text.split()[1]
    position = message.text.split()[2]

    # print(first, last, position)
    create_user_db(message.chat.id, first, last, position)


def create_user_db(id_tlgrm, first, last, position):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    db_data = [(id_tlgrm, first, last, position)]
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', db_data)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Если ответ является решением вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его таковым. Это поможет другим пользователям.